# Looking for responsive css-only carousel (no js)

Tags: css, web, gallery, carousel, web-deployment

Anyway, is there any CSS-carousel project not using JS, or at least with the simplest javascript code possible? Dont want to load jquery for a simple carousel.
**By the way, i need a stripe of images(lets say 10 images with 3 or 5 visible) with next/prev controls on the sides.**

Comment: You can create one using CSS `:target` pseudo-selector. BTW the ~fifth google result for "css carousel": http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/

Comment: +1 for cssscience. I recently re-purposed that and it was pretty cooperative.

Comment: @pawel Thanx mate, it's not in my relional google output though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated above, I stripped down the cssscience example and I have placed it in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Tx3T/

The key in this is the use of the checkbox trick and the css code here:

```
  #slide1:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:0; }
  #slide2:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-100%; }
  #slide3:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-200%; }
  #slide4:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-300%; }
  #slide5:checked ~ #slides .inner { margin-left:-400%; }
```

It shifts the images left or right the width of the container as needed.

This fiddle shrinks the images (for fiddle purpose) and then opened up the "window" to show 2 images at once, and then slides them two at a time:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Tx3T/1/

Comment: Awesome, thanx a lot. Is there any way to modify it to my requirement, so one could see three images simultaneusly?

Comment: you can resize the div to show the other images as needed, and adjust the percentages to slide the other images in as needed. Feel free to +1 and Accept if you like the answer.

Comment: i can't +1, sorry, not enough reputation.